# Elif program mixing integers and strings

Tags: python-3.x, windows

No matter what I write the output is always (err).

I am a beginner learning Python 3.

Tried to make an if elif program but it is giving strange output.

```
z = input()

if z == 1:

    print ('one')

elif z == 2:

    print ("two")

else: print ("err")
```

I expected the output to be 'one' if I write 1 and 'two' if I write 2.

Comment: in Python 3 `input` always returns a string, and a string is never equal to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` will always return you a `string` value. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp)

You will need to cast your input as an `int` to do the comparisons.

Using your example:

```
z = input()

if int(z) == 1:

    print ('one')

elif int(z) == 2:

    print ("two")

else: 
    print ("err")
```

or even

```
z = int(input())

if z == 1:

    print ('one')

elif z == 2:

    print ("two")

else: 
    print ("err")
```

Hope this helps!